# [cpp.cond]/2 in N4713

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor

[cpp.cond]/2 in N4713:

> A *defined-macro-expression* evaluates to `1` if the identifier is
>   currently defined as a macro name (that is, if it is predefined **or**
>   if it has been the subject of a `#define` preprocessing directive
>   without an intervening `#undef` directive with the same subject
>   identifier), `0` if it is not.

I don't understand the **or** above. That is, how can a macro name be predefined without being the subject of a `#define` preprocessing directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation predefines some macros, without the user having to `#define` them. A list of standard predefined macro names can be found in [cpp.predefined]. It includes, for example, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

Answer (score 2):

Because compilers can create macros. They do it all the time, and this statement is part of what allows them to do that. In fact, the standard *requires* them to; there are a [slew of macros](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cpp.predefined) that the standard requires that implementations provide. These include `__cplusplus` (the C++ version), `__FILE__` (the name of the file being processed), and so forth.